# Hide OOTB Markup Styles dropdown for RichHTML field in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, dropdown, rich-text, markup

I need to hide or inactivate the OOTB markup styles dropdown from the ribbon of RichHTML field.

I have tried the RichHtmlField.AllowTextMarkup property but it controls the individual properties not the markup dropdown.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery to hide the Markup styles by

$("#Ribbon\.EditingTools\.CPEditTab\.Markup-LargeMedium-0-0").hide()